# Position the box to bottom of the td

Tags: c#, css

[image]

The black box is stand for the images that user upload, it is fix the width but the height is free size. I want to put the position of the three gray box on the bottom of td ( like the middle gray box). I used position:absolute, and bottom:0 But if doesn't work.

I have no idea how can I do that.

Comment: What are you using? GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a table then you can not do it in the same cell, because `td` elements cannot take `position:relative`.

You need to either restructure your code to not use `table` or use a new row `tr` and put the gray boxes in there (demo at http://jsfiddle.net/SWRXW/) ..

Comment: I want to do like what you said too, but each column is query from 1 row in database, that's why I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @socheata, you will likely need to store the results in memory (*a list of some sort*) and loop it twice in order to create two rows..

Comment: In the gray  box are contain data in 3 fields of my table in database, so if I want to store those 3 field in one list, How can I do that? I hope you don't mind to answer because I am one beginner developer in asp.net mvc c# :). Thanks.