# Store the results in memory (List) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to store many record that I query from database in list , one record has 10 fields, in order to loop it later.
But I have no idea to do that. Anyone can answer me please.

Comment: Why not just store it in a data table?

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc with c#, Can I store it in data table?

Comment: How are you querying the database?

Comment: Sorry about that-I am not sure but I don't see why not, and a datatable is in memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350846/position-the-box-to-bottom-of-the-td/8350903#8350903. You can watch this link, I have ask at there but no one can answer it.

Comment: question is vague and unclear and doesn't give any detail as to what the data structure is that houses the records after the database query or how they were extracted from the database.

Comment: Stick to your original question, it's much clearer. I don't think any answer you get to this one will be solving the problem you describe there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a good practice to store data and loop through among them.

Create Model/POCO class as:

```
public class DataClassName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Create properties according to your fields
}
```

Fill and get data list:

```
public List<DataClassName> GetDataList()
{
    List<DataClassName> dataList = new List<DataClassName>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from TargetTableName";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = 
                   new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataList.Add(
                        new DataClassName()
                            {
                                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
                                Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"])
                                //Set all property according to your fields
                            });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex_)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

Save data that is returned from GetDataList() into your datalist and loop through among the data as required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd go about storing it in a `DataTable`:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionStringHere");
SqlCommand GetData = new SqlCommand();
GetData.Connection = conn;
GetData.CommandText = "select * from yourTable"; // or whatever your query is, whether ad hoc or stored proc
// add parameters here if your query needs it

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(GetData);
DataTable YourData = new DataTable();

try
{
    sda.Fill(YourData);
}
catch
{
    sda.Dispose();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

If you have 10 fields, you'd be hard-pressed to store your data in a `List<T>` object.  Your best bet would be to create a class tailored to the data you are looking to retrieve (if you want to take it a step further than the `DataTable` implementation above) with corresponding properties/fields.

Comment: If I do this, so how can I get it and display it in my web page? Please have a look at the detail in here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350846/position-the-box-to-bottom-of-the-td/8350903#8350903

Comment: @socheata well you basically have a `DataTable` instance that contains your data.  So you can do whatever it is  you need with that data.  Loop through the rows/columns, or do what you would normally do with it at your disposal.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could give a bit more information...

If you use the entity framework or similar to query the database, it will probably return an enumerable object.. you just need to call `.ToList()` on this to save it as a list.

Do you mean that you want to store this across web requests? Then you could store it in the HttpRuntime.Cache collection, allowing for it to expire after some time.

Alternatively store it in a static property. Session is also an option but it doesn't sound like the best option for this

Comment: This is the detail of my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350846/position-the-box-to-bottom-of-the-td/8350903#8350903

Comment: There is no reason to sign your posts; doing so is redundant (your screen name is on every post) and doing it repeatedly could lead to suspension.  I suggest to do not continue this practice.

Comment: @ casperOne : But no one can answer my old question, so what can I do beside like this?